# Creating a colored margin without changing DOM, because border affects the markup like padding

Tags: javascript, css

I was trying to see if there was a way to do something like changing the color of margins in CSS, without changing the DOM, but i am unsure as to how to figure it out.  Margin itself takes only things like "auto|inherit|number (px|$|vs|vh)" so i did not know if it was a combination of a few things.

How would i accomplish such a thing?

My bet seems to be on actually doing DOM manipulation.

Is my goal achievable with CSS alone?

My reasoning is that i am doing some scaling for a visual demo, and want to add a black border, similar to that of IPads and other Tablets.  The issues i noticed is that adding a border which scales everything a little more (not what i wanted).

The reason why i am tagging javascript is because there might be a trick within javascript, outside the scope of css that would resolve the issue (while not changing DOM around).

Is this possible?  Had anyone ever tried this?

Comment: I would like to know why i am getting a downvote?  I might be able to adjust my question accordingly to not get downvotes?  Thanks.

Comment: What about [border-left](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-left.asp) (or you can obviously use `border:` or `border-right:`, and so on) ?

Comment: when i did:  `border: solid 50px black;` it was making the content smaller (because im transforming the scale.  When i was looking at: the the picture of where margin/border/padding sit in relation to the object itself, i noticed that border actually pushes into the div, sort of like padding.

Comment: I wanted to sort of do a soft wrap of the object in a sense, to not change and make the content smaller.  I was noticing this because the width of the content went from 600px scaled down, to about 500px scaled down.

Comment: `box-sizing:border-box` ??

Comment: @Paulie_D Never tried that.   Let me take a look at the CSS definition.

Comment: @Paulie_D it still seemed to shrink

Comment: A margin is only a space, and as such _has_ no “color”.

Comment: knew that going in.  Luckily, the box-shadow accomplished exactly what i wanted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create colored borders without using any extra dom elements... You have a couple of different options -- probably more.

Using box shadow:

```
.foo {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: green;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px black;
}
```

Using a linear gradient on a pseudo-element:

```
.bar {
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: orange;   
}

.bar:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #000)
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5rLUh/)**

Hopefully I'm not misunderstanding what you're after...

Comment: Box shadow was in fact what i was looking for.  It didnt push any dimensions around... it did a soft wrapper, which was the exact answer.